# spring-data-aerospike compatibility matrix

Tags: spring-data, aerospike

Hi looking for guidance on a version of spring-data-aerospike for Springboot 2.4.2. I don't see it listed [here](https://github.com/aerospike-community/spring-data-aerospike#spring-data-aerospike-compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't a specific spring-data-aerospike version that used Spring Boot `2.4.2`.

- spring-data-aerospike `2.4.2.RELEASE` used Spring Boot `2.3.5.RELEASE`.
- spring-data-aerospike `2.5.0/3.0.0` used Spring Boot `2.5.1`.
- spring-data-aerospike `3.0.1` is using Spring Boot `2.5.3`.

Using the latest spring-data-aerospike is recommended, if you can I would consider an upgrade, if its not an option - I would suggest using the latest version possible that works with your current version of Spring Boot (probably 2.4.2.RELEASE).